# Avoid printing of 'tee' trace line

Tags: bash, shell-script, trace, set

I have the following in a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

logFile='script.log'
echo -n > $logFile
log="tee -a $logFile"

set -x
scp ... user@host:...
ssh user@host "
  echo '...message...'
  " 2>&1 | $log
{ set +x ;} 2> /dev/null  # avoids trace output of '++ set +x'
```

The output is:

```bash
++ ssh user@host '
  echo '\''> ...message...'\''
  '
++ tee -a script.log
> ...message...
```

Can the `++ tee ...` trace line be suppressed somehow, as well?

Comment: Regarding `log="tee -a $logFile"` - Don't store a command in a variable, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, use a function `log() { tee -a "$logFile"; }`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the hint. But then the trace output contains even more uninteresting: `++ log\n++ tee -a script.log`.

Comment: Not if you do as @fra-san suggests and just don't include the logging in the `set -x` scope,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may enable tracing for the appropriate command only, instead of doing it for the whole pipeline. Each command in a multi-command pipeline runs in its own subshell execution environment (except for the last one, in Bash, when the `lastpipe` option is in effect) and different `set` options can be applied to each of them.

E.g., generalizing your code a bit, to have `+tee` not printed out in

```bash
$ set -x; echo foo | tee; { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
+ echo foo
+ tee
foo
```

a simple way could be

```bash
$ { set -x; echo foo; } | tee
+ echo foo
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to [fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/315749/fra-san) for [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710269/88374) and [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) for his comment to [the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/710266/88374).

I ended up with a solution with a `log` function and less overloaded code lines:

```bash
log() {
  tee -a "$logFile"
  }

logFile='script.log'
> $logFile

{
set -x
scp ...
ssh ...
} 2>&1 | log
```

Comment: Minor point: `echo -n > $logFile` could simply be `>"$logFile"`. `echo` does nothing and quoting expansions is a good habit in general (especially when posting script snippets on the Internet ;-), even if they are not needed in this specific case.

Comment: @fra-san Thx again for the '`>`' hint. I heard/read that "quote expansions" many times already. The matter is that editors with syntax coloring (i.e. [Bash Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bash-editor) for Eclipse) color quoted vars as string and without it as variables which is more natural. Especially for a 3GL developer more familiar wit C[++], Java, C#, JS, etc. So I like to avoid such quotes when they're not syntactically necessary.